# Problem with java XML Parsing - FactoryConfigurationError: Provider not found

Tags: java, xml, provider

I have a java applet that parses a string of xml.  However, running the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document d = db.parse(xml);
```

Generates the following error:

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider <HTML> not found
```

Some forums I've checked prior to posting indicated that I need to add 2 jar files - xercesImpl.jar and xmlParserAPIs.jar - to my JRE_HOME/lib/ext directory.  However, I don't think this is the problem because this applet is currently hosted on 2 different webservers and one functions perfectly while the other fails.  I looked, and neither have those jars in the jre/lib/ext directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, I added xercesImpl to the applet archive on the webserver that was screwing up, and things work peachy king.  I have no idea why it is functioning in the other environment without this jar (maybe it's there and I just didn't see it).